# Simple JavaScript plus php database access

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Here is what i an trying to do:

I have a database table with two fields. One is to hold a url, and the second is to hold a line of descriptive text. This field set will be updated constantly by another script.

What i need to do is run a timer that will check the database table for either of those fields to be non-null, and then retrieve the contents, display the contents of the url field in the iframe, and display the contents of the text field in a text line at the bottom of the page.

I want this to happen every 1000 milliseconds. What would be the correct method to do this?

Comment: You want to access an SQL database via javascript?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? It seems odd to be replacing an array of urls in a bunch of iframes every second....

Comment: I want to access database thru php. But i need an auto function to do this each second without stopping the entire page from running.

Comment: use setTimeout ......

Comment: `setTimeout` will run only once - use `setInterval`

Answer (score 0):

Edited

you simply should put your ajax code inside a setTimeout Javascript function to load it with your desired interval.
lets assume that your text field has an id of #textfield. and your php file does the job for retrieving infos from DB.

```
setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "yourfile.php",
        type: "GET", // or post
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',  
        success: function (result) {
            $("#textfield").val(result.test);
        }
    });
}, 1000);
```

i hope it helps

Comment: I will look into this deeper when i get home. I need to dump the new url (which might only be updated every 30 seconds or more) into an iframe at the top of the page and dump the text description (i suspect no quicker than 5-10 seconds between text field updates). Thats all i am looking to do for this very moment.

Comment: `setTimeout` will run only once. If you want to run the process every 1000 milliseconds use `setInterval()`

Comment: I have been trying to understand this code. I am more familiar with html, css, php than i am with JavaScript, let alone ajax. If i get this script working as needed, does this need to go in the head or the body?